# Will the Expo allow development testing in an environment as rigorous as a real device?

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm working on a small project using React-Native and Expo. I've been developing through Expo Go and have completed all the tests through it.

Then I built the app with EAS and installed it on a real device, and the app crashed at a certain part. When I checked logcat for logs, I got the following error.

[image: error-msg]

> Cannot use the AuthSession proxy because the project full name is not defined.

The error isn't the problem, I've certainly never seen this in Expo Go. I've had issues with crashes before and fixed them, but the repetition of fixing one issue and then rebuilding is very tiring. Is there any way to set up a rigorous environment to test the behavior?

ps. I don't speak English very well, so I used a translator. Sorry.

I had no issues when I ran Expo Go with the following command: `npx expo start --no-dev --tunnel --minify`.

I also tried this with an Android emulator, but the results were the same.